# What is the maximum lumens an Infrared LED can dissipate?

Tags: infrared

I am planning to shoot a video under Infrared light and want to choose a ton of the right size so that the entire room is illuminated. I am on to build a separate circuit if need be for better visibility. Please suggest

Comment: Be aware that the human iris does not react to IR; be sure to have enough visible illumination to keep pupils narrowed to reduce damage to vision.

Comment: Different models of LED will have different brightness specs.

Comment: The lumen measures visible light. A proper IR LED produces 0 lumens. A real IR LED will probably produce a tiny visible output in the red band. But knowing how bright this to the eye tells you nothing about how IR cameras will see it.

Comment: I think it may be best to just experiment. I mean, yeah, the problem could be solved analytically. But only if you know a whole bunch of stuff that you probably don't know.

Comment: If the camera has the IR filter removed and is sensitive to low light consider at least 20 to 30W of IR emitters in a series array with current regulated and at least 30 sq in of alum substrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a spotlight with +-20 deg above camera get 50 of these https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/osram-opto-semiconductors-inc/SFH-4544/475-3524-ND/5231484

- run them off 12,24 or 48V with 1.2V 50mA per 5mm LED in an array.

If you want no shadows with ceiling reflection or suitable ceiling panels replicate these boards x20! And get 1000 pcs
 With 1000 LEDs at 1.2V * 50mA *1k pc =60W which is can be low current telephone or magnet wire if using a 48V supply. If you recess the LED board with a frame edge then you can design the ceiling to be glare free from camera shots with suitable geometry.

Ghost photoshooting ?

Comment: Thanks Tony... Let me explore.. Am not looking at ghost photo shoot, but wanted to try this for one event...

Comment: Strong flood light or no shadow ceiling light? The differences are huge. Flood light intensity is inverse squared to object distance while planar ceiling light is only inverse to object reflect path distance but a greater distance so more uniform